# Porting Windows Queues/Stack to android

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, porting

I was thinking to port Queues and stack used in Windows to Android. Is it possible to do the same? Can it be done with the help of Android NDK?

Comment: please elobrate your question

Answer (score 1):

Why? `std::queue` and `std::stack` are already available on Android.